# iOS: is it good practice to have multiple unconnected screens in one storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm building a few information screens and they have different layout/design (ie. can't be generalised), since they are all information screens I've put them in one storyboard, however they are not connected by any segue, it's just based on response I show different information screens.

I'm a bit uncertain that if it's a good practice to do this? I can't think of another way for doing this which is better, separated XIBs? different storyboards? Or a single screen with dynamically updated layout/content based on design (this sounds like a bad idea)?

The only downside I can think of, is that the storyboard won't have a initial screen, which feels a bit against the purpose of storyboard - you are telling a "story" by screens in a navigation flow.

Am I thinking correctly, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two good reasons **not** to put independent scenes in a single storyboard:

- A larger storyboard takes longer to load and save.
- If this is a multi-person project, you’re more likely to run into merge conflicts.

Here’s one good reason to put independent scenes in a single storyboard:

- You will often need to modify several of the scenes at once.

Usually it’s simpler and lighter-weight to use individual XIBs unless you actually need storyboard-specific features like segues.

Comment: "A larger storyboard takes longer to load and save" But let's be clear that you mean only while developing in Xcode. There is nothing that takes "longer" at runtime; the storyboard doesn't load a nib unless it needs it.

Comment: Yes, I meant it takes longer to edit a larger storyboard in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense. I think the only reason for me to have a single storyboard is to "group" the information screens (with different layout/design) together. They have no dependency on each other.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of adding the screens in a storyboard is, you can connect them via storyboard references.

It is not always necessary for a story board to have an initial controller.

Actually it is more of a personal choice to choose story board vs xib in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking the same, just not sure whether it's good to have screens not connected in a single storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just stipulate, shall we, that having multiple screens but not representing them through multiple view controllers and their views is just dumb. View controllers exist for a reason; use them. So your choices for making a view controller's view are:

- Create the interface entirely in code
- Use a `xib` file
- Use a storyboard

You are asking to choose between the last two. But as far as you are concerned, there is nothing to choose between, because:

- A `xib` file is a way of generating a nib. So many `xib` files give you many nibs.
- A storyboard is a *collection* of nibs (i.e. it's multiple nibs in one) — with the added feature that you can include segues.

If you don't use segues, a storyboard is many nibs and that's all it is — just like having many `xib` files. So if you are *not* going to use segues between view controllers in your storyboard, then there is no advantage or disadvantage one way or the other: it just depends on your personal style.

Personally I think the storyboard interface is a pain to use, plus if you want to instantiate a view controller from a storyboard without using a segue, you have to give it an identifier and cast to the view controller class, whereas if you instantiate a view controller with an eponymous `xib`, you instantiate it by class and it loads its view automatically, which is far neater.

So I'd lean towards using separate `xib` files, but it's a matter of opinion / taste, and *de gustibus non disputandum*.